# How to copy visible pivot item data to a cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

[image]

I have country code in pivot report filter. I would like to get the visible piviot item data and place each values in each cell from A1. I used the code below. But All the cell showing only last value in filter. I need to move automatically from A1 .Help me

```
Sub Getpivotitem()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str1 As Variant
Dim Data As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:X1")
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim pi As PivotItem
For Each pi In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Country Code").PivotItems
    If pi.Visible = True Then
        For Each cell In rng.Columns
        cell.Value = pi
        Next cell
     End If
Next pi

End Sub
```

Comment: Your pivot table data is different than your expected result. Where is `FR`, `DE`, `ES` .... in your pivot table?

Comment: @harun24hr Yes i selected those values in Values in my pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is being caused by your nested loop. I think this is what you're looking for

```
Sub Getpivotitem()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim str1 As Variant, Data As Variant
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim j As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = Range("A1:X1")

    For Each pi In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Country Code").PivotItems
        If pi.Visible = True Then
            j = j + 1
            ws.cells(1, j) = pi
        End If
    Next pi

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Non VBA approach for Excel 2010 or later: Simply make a copy of the PivotTable, and remove all fields from it except for the Country Code field. Move the Country Code field to either the ROWS or the COLUMNS pane, and connect both PivotTables with a Slicer. Bingo: You've got a list showing you whatever selections are made in the PivotTable. Even better, users can simply use the Slicer to make those selections.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will copy and paste all visible values fro `Country Code` column to `A1`, `B1`, `C1` ....... cells.

```
Sub CopyVisiblesValues()

    Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "'Country Code'[All]", xlLabelOnly + xlFirstRow, True
        Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Here `Country Code` is column header of pivot table as well as column header of source data. You may need to adjust `Country Code` with your one.

Comment: Its coping only the header. Not the values which is present inside the filter

Comment: Can you please share a sample workbook. Share it in google drive then give link in comment. The code is working on my computer.